# Mac Backup Software that can run from a CD/DVD

Tags: macos, backup, bootable-disk

I've been googling around and I've found several backup programs for Mac like Carbon Copy, SuperDuper and ChronoSync.
They all seem to offer the option to create bootable backups but that's not what I want because I don't want to devote my entire external 1TB drive to this.

I'm a seasoned windows user but I recently moved to Mac. I'm looking for a program that can run from a DVD (like **Acronis True Image** for Windows). That way my backups are just files in my drive and I can restore them whenever I want using the bootable program.

Also, if you know a better way to accomplish what I want please share it.

Comment: What do you get from running the backup application from DVD (compared to running it from the `/Applications` folder)?

Comment: I don't mind running it from the Applications folder, that's fine. What I don't want is to dedicate my external drive just to that. I think the applications that create bootable backups use the whole external drive for that purpose (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: Isn't the requirement to have the backup application start from DVD a bit misleading then? If it is not a hard requirement you might get better answers by removing it.

Comment: Having the software run from DVD would be my preferred choice. I'm willing to pay for it, I'm not looking for a freebie.

Answer (score 3):

This might be considered pure opinion rather than fact, but I'd say just dedicate a spare HD to it & set up Time Machine. I use both Win & Mac here, Macs backed to Time Machine & Win to Acronis. Time Machine wins hands down.

The Time Machine can be used to recover files when your OS X HD is crashed. Just put in a new drive, recover from Time machine and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different software including linux-based products such as Clonezilla but in the end the best solution I could find was doing a sector-by-sector disk clone using Acronis True Image.

Every backup software that runs from a CD and supports sector-by-sector cloning should work.

PS: I just bought a bigger hard drive for my Mac and this cloning method worked like a charm.